# How to use AuthenticationProperties in Owin or How to find out which middleware extension successfully executed

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

i am using owin middleware for authentication. I am using 3 middleware extensions eg bearer, custom1, custom2.

After authentication has happened, I want to know in my authhorization code, which of the middleware extension was successful in authenticating. 
I tried to achieve it by inserting a property in AuthenticationTicket

```
 Dictionary<string, string> statevalues = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "successful", "true" } };
AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties(statevalues);
AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, props);
```

But I couldn't find how to read back these properties. 
They were not available in HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes() also.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you look at ClaimsIdentity.AuthenticationType?

Comment: You can get the auth properties from HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenicateAsync

Comment: @Tratcher but that will result in entire authentication being done again?

Comment: No, most middleware cache the result.